# Use one List<> to remove entries from another List<>

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists, with one common element

```
List<myObject> myObj (contains ID, name, other stuff)
1, Dave, stuff
2, Albert, stuff
10, James, stuff
15, Rita, stuff

List<int> myID (contains ID)
2,
10
```

What I need to do, is remove any entries from myObj, where myObj.ID is in myID.ID

(bear in mind that for the real code, both lists are much longer)

Comment: what about join ?

Comment: For which language?

Comment: @DominiqueLorre The question is clearly tagged as c#

Comment: @juharr I didn't see any tag when I asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a `HashSet<int>` from the id list for fast lookup, and then use [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var idSet = new HashSet<int>(myID);
myObj.RemoveAll(item => idSet.Contains(item.ID));
```

Comment: strangely, I was working along these lines earlier, but couldn't get it to work, which appears to be that I was using the wrong type for the HashSet (n00bie mistake) .... you're example is spot on and it's pretty damn quick, too.